# Adding slide effect by anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open another `searchpage.html` html page with slide effects for which i used `anchor` tag.

```
<a id="add" href="searchpage.html" class="show_hide">Click</a>
```

And js:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //to prevent default action of link tag
            $(this).toggle('slide','left',100);
        });
 });
```

But its showing error:

```
TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function
```

Comment: A jsFiddle is much appreciated.

Comment: toggle syntax is $(selector).toggle(speed,easing,callback) but in yours code its saying something else please check toggle syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, this may help You..

HTML :

```
<a id="add" href="searchpage.html" class="show_hide">Click</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //to prevent default action of link tag
        $('#add').slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

And Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hardy_411/cnrn2at8/1/).

Comment: what is the use of id=add?

Comment: @Dimple
You can use id as an Identifier for an Element, Here in Your Example : anchor tag will be identified by `add`. suppose there is another anchor tag with id=something than you can identify these both anchor tags by its Ids.

Comment: I know that but their is nothing use of it here

Comment: There it is, @themis has edited the Code, Check it out.